# codeigniter sql

Tags: codeigniter

can someone please help me to convert this mysql query to convert it to CodeIgniter SQL method

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX( SUBSTRING( locationID , 3, 11 ) ) 
FROM items WHERE LEFT( locationID , 2 ) = = ? "
```

Having values such as location id's such as AK23, LI343, JE343 etc.. it returns the highest integer matching the prefix(JE, LI - given 2 character prefix in the where clause)

It will be great if you can please help me with this as the normal way of wriring sql in the model does not work..

Thanks alot

Comment: @Trickster If i assign this to a string variable and run the sql using with non-codeigniter environment, it works fine.. but for some reason when I try to do it in CodeIgniter it returns NULL value.... what I mean by normal way is  the sql statement that i'd run in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

db->query('SELECT MAX( SUBSTRING( locationID , 3, 11 ) ) 
FROM items WHERE LEFT( locationID , 2 ) = ?', array(args)

db->select('MAX(SUBSTRING( locationID , 3, 11))')->from('items')->where('LEFT( locationID , 2)', arg)->get()

hope that help

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I tried this 
  
    $query = $this->db->select('MAX( CAST( SUBSTRING(locationID , 3, 11) AS UNSIGNED))')->from('items')->where('LEFT(locationID , 2 )', $locationPrefix)->get();

    var_dump ($query);

it gives a database error.. What have I done wrong there?